# Accessing Public 2D Array Variables via Script in Unity

Tags: arrays

So I figured out how to make a 2D array that is viewable in the inspector via the code below.

```
[System.Serializable]
 public class QuestPhase {
     [HideInInspector]
     public string name;
     public int[] Phase = new int[5];
 }
 public QuestPhase[] questPhase    = new QuestPhase[5];
```

That works just fine, but I'm trying to figure out how to access that information via script and I can't figure it out.

```
 questVariable = questPhase[1,1];
```

That returns an error of "Expected 1 index, got 2", and just using one index gives me "Cannot convert type QuestPhase into type int." I'm sure the answer is obvious, but if anyone could answer it for me I would be most appreciative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When it says `expected 1 index, got 2`, that's because your `questPhase` variable is a `QuestPhase[]`--that is, a one-dimensional array of `QuestPhase`s. You index it simply by `questPhase[1]`.

At this point, it seems that you're trying to use `questPhase[1]` as an `int`, even though it is in fact of type `Phase`. You probably want to do `questPhase[1].Phase[1]` to get the second `QuestPhase` object, and the second `Phase` from that.

```
questVariable = questPhase[1].Phase[1];
```

Comment: Aaaah I was so close with the syntax I was trying. Thank you so much!

Comment: @Tim Glad I could help. :)